What exactly is the translational partition function for a single particle system?
I am recently reading Daniel V. Schroeder's book on thermal physics, and I am having trouble with the translational partition function for a single particle. Particularly since he defines the partition function as the sum of the Boltzmann factors for all "possible" states ( pg 229, section 2: Average values, chapter: Boltzmann statistics ). Then he calculates the translational partition function for a single molecule in one dimension(pg 253, section 7:Ideal Gas Revisited, chapter: Boltzmann statistics)  as:
$Z_{1d} = \sum_{n} e^{-\frac{E_n}{kT}} = \sum_{n} e^{-\frac{h^2 n^2}{8mL^2 kT}} \approx \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{h^2 n^2}{8mL^2 kT}} \, dn = \sqrt{\frac{2 \pi m kT}{h^2}} L$
But now my question is, if the partition functon is the sum of the Boltzmann factors for all the possible states, then how can we write this sum? How can all these infinite states be possible for a single particle? Even in the context of many particles,  how can all these states be possible, since a box of particles have a definite energy, how and why should we sum it to infinity?

If the particle is not confined then its energy eigenvalues are not quantized. Thus the partition function is an integral over all of phase space with complicated behavior.

It seems that your difficulty is not related to the specific case of the translational partition function of one degree of freedom but to the definition of the canonical partition function itself.
Independently of the Hamiltonian and the number of degrees of freedom, the canonical partition function is always defined as the sum over all the states, from the ground state to arbitrarily high energies. The exponential function makes exponentially small the contribution of the energies significantly larger than $kT$. The main conceptual issue is that at the constant temperature characterizing the canonical ensemble, a box of particles has a well definite average energy but not a constant energy. Indeed, in the canonical ensemble, the thermal contact with a reservoir implies the presence of arbitrarily large energy fluctuations, although with an exponentially decreasing probability.
